# How to change JAVA_HOME temprorary with env command

Tags: linux, debian, environment-variables, java

I use openjdk for my work, but sometimes I need oracle's JRE. I thought that I could use 'env' command for this, but can't figure out why it's not working.
I have 
openjdk in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` and 
oracle's jdk in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64`
when I'm running:
 `env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64 java -version`
i get:

`java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)`

but if i try: `env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64 env|grep JAVA`
I see:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64`

I have 'feeling' that this is somehow related to process forking and inheritance. I know that i can simply use export name=variable command and etc. But would appreciate get explanation is it possible with 'env' command and how. Thank you! (I am using debian linux, unstable repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that using the env command, however you have to use a little work around and call `sh`, see the following code snippets:

```
# env var=bla echo $var
>
# env var=bla sh -c 'echo $var'
> bla
# echo $var
>
```

You can find more information using on `info coreutils 'env invocation'`

Unfortunatelly I can't give you any further explanations why it only works using `sh -c ''`.

It seems `env` has a rather non-intuitive behavior...

```
# env PATH= echo $PATH
> env: echo: No such file or directory
# env PATH= /bin/echo $PATH
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've found one misleading in my question: `java -version` depends on `/usr/bin/java` link destination. So, if i would like 'fully' switch java environment for specific task i should change JAVA_HOME and `/usr/bin/java` or `/etc/alternatives/java` link destination. And I really intersted what is smartest way to do this. Should I open new question?

Comment: I've started new question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212139/how-to-switch-java-environment-for-specific-process

Comment: The reason is that "$var" gets expanded to the contents of that variable before the command is run.  So 'env' saw an argument list of the previous value of $var.