# How to switch java environment for specific process?

Tags: environment-variables, java

I use openjdk in my work, but sometimes I need oracle's jre or even specific version of oracle's jre. As I know, I should update `JAVA_HOME` value and `/usr/bin/java` or `/etc/alternatives/java` link destination. Is there a smart/secure/easy way to make these changes temporary for specific process? Thank you! (I am using debian linux unstable repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a smart/secure/easy way to make these changes temporary for specific process?

Environment variables such as `$JAVA_HOME` are inherited, not global to the system.  So if you set one a specific way, it applies only to that process, and if exported, any process it spawns.

The process here would be a shell instance; you can either do this on the command line or create something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/oracle/java/bin:$PATH
export $PATH
exec whatever.jar
```

In case you are unfamiliar with how `$PATH` works, the directories are checked in order, so in this case `/opt/oracle/java/bin` will be searched before anything else, and when `java` is needed, the one there will be used.

You could elaborate this to use arguments when you invoke it to specify which `.jar` or `.class` file to execute, and some shorthand arg for which java installation to use, e.g. `if [[ $1 == 2 ]]; then PATH=/opt/oracle2/java/bin...`.

That `$PATH` (and `$JAVA_HOME`, if you do that too) will only apply to the script and anything it starts.

If you're working on something, you can `export` the variables in one terminal and it will continue to apply there and only there.  If you have the JDK installed, the same `bin` directory contains `javac`, etc.

Comment: Brilliant! '...the directories are checked in order...' that what i've totally forgotten. Was thinking how to exclude /usr/bin/java from PATH when whole dir /usr/bin is there, now it's clear. Thank you!